# Sometimes getting GPS location late i.e. more than one minute in android

Tags: android, gps

I developed an application that fetches GPS location. I specified minTime as 20 seconds and minDistance as 1 meter in requestLocationUpdate method. But still i am getting location in 2-3 seconds interval and sometimes it takes more than one minute. Can i get location at particular time interval and within 1 minute?

Please Help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i get location at particular time interval and within 1 minute?

Not necessarily.

First, you set `minDistance` to 1 meter. Try using 0.

Second, you are limited by how frequently the GPS radio actually gets fixes, which will be based on environmental factors and is outside of your control.

Third, `minTime` is a hint, as the documentation explains. Hence, you may get fixes more frequently than it, or less frequently. For a `minTime` of 20 seconds, it is unlikely that Android will power down the GPS radio between fixes, and so I suspect that value is not helping you any.